# how to add more items from edittext to recyclerview in android

Tags: android

i am using recyclerview to show my list. the input i take is from edittext. when i click the save button it shows only one row. how do i add more items to the list..this is my code

**MycardViewAdapter.class**

```
public class MyCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCardViewAdapter.myViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Student> student;

public MyCardViewAdapter(Context context, List<Student> student){
    this.context = context;
    this.student = student;
}

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
     Student s = student.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(s.getName());
    holder.surname.setText(s.getSurname());
    holder.age.setText(s.getAge());
    holder.marks.setText(s.getMarks());

}

public void updateList(List<Student> student)
{
    student = student;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void addItem(int position, Student stud)
{
    student.add(position, stud);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return student.size();
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       TextView name,surname,age,marks;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardname);
        surname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardsurname);
        age = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardage);
        marks = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardmarks);
    }
  }

}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name,surname,age,marks;
Button save;
MyCardViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Student> student;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surname);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    marks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marks);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    student = new ArrayList<Student>();
    adapter = new MyCardViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,student);



    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lmmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lmmanager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            student.add(new Student(name.getText().toString(),surname.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString(),marks.getText().toString()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your save button, add this code. 

RecyclerView.LayoutManager lmmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()); recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lmmanager);
student.add(new Student(name.getText().toString(), surname.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString(), marks.getText().toString())); 
adapter = new MyCardViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, student);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Don't set adapter on each click. That makes `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` useless.

Comment: yeah i'll remember that...thanks for all your help guys...:)